# Reroute any subdirectory to script

Tags: php, apache, perl, .htaccess

I am trying to setup simple url routing in a Perl web project without haveing to include a framework just for that purpose. I believe this can be accomplished with an .htaccess.

The plan is for any request to the server using `example.com/anysubdirectory/...` to be routed to a perl/php script that will parse whatever is contained in `/anysubdirectory/...` and the parameters following it and then determine where to send the user based on that info.

If example.com without any subdirectory is requested I need to still maintain the default behavior of searching for an index page here.

Since the `/anysubdirectory/` will be dynamic i'm not able to predefine that `/123/ -> option 1` or `/abc/ -> option 2`

I am not overly familiar with htaccess other than the typical www and base rewrites.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I answered my own question using the following in the root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.pl?action=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This seems to be working with my initial testing.

I believe this is how it is working:

- If the requested subdirectory is not found as a file
- If the requested subdirectory is not found as a directory
- Redirect this to the router.pl script along with any leftover parameters from the original url.

**EDIT: The above is not working completely, this is still redirecting any file that is not found on the server to the router.pl script. Not really the functionality that I am looking for,i would like this to only happen if it is a subdirectory and not an invalid file**

Not sure I want any bot thats guessing filenames to be pegging my script on a regular basis.

Please correct this response if any of the above is not accurate.

Comment: Since you say so `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, it will redirect if it is not a file. If you want it for exisiting directories, say so `-d`.